# How to run command at startup?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, xmodmap

The Return key in my keyboard is broken, so I have chosen to make my PgDn key to act like the Return key. Now I learned how to do this using 'xmodmap'. The command I have to run is:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 117 = Return'
```

But I have to run this command everytime I reboot. I googled around and found that placing this command in the /etc/rc.local file should run it automatically at start-up. However, it does not work.

Can anyone tell me how can I execute this command when I boot up? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Where exactly did you place your command in the file? After or before `exit 0`?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I don't see anything to do with the GUI in this question, and your answer isn't a GUI answer..

Comment: @Seth my answer *is* a GUI answer, and does not work when logging in via command line, while the supposed duplicate Karel mentioned explicitely asked for a solution that also works for non-GUI.

Answer (score 5):

Although you asked for a solution *on startup*, this might do what you want as well: to run a command *on login*, on user level, here is a simple one:

For example, to set the <kbd>PageDown</kbd> key as <kbd>Return</kbd> key on login:

Create a .desktop file as below, save it in `~/.config/autostart`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Set Keyboard
Exec=xmodmap -e 'keycode 117 = Return'
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Copy the text above, paste it into an empty textfile (gedit), save it as set_keyboard.desktop (or anything_else.desktop) in `~/.config/autostart`

Comment: No. I want to run the command on startup, even before login. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to run commands at on user login (which is the best way to accomplish what you want) is to add the command to the `.profile` file (located in `/home/[user]/`).  You want to add the command to the end of the file.  For example:

```
[user@host ~]# nano .profile
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# Remap Return key to Page Down on login
xmodmap -e 'keycode 117 = Return'
```

You should be able to logout and log back in to make this change take effect.  However, it may be best just to reboot (to fully test it out).